# How to set different tab width in prettier for different file format?

Tags: vscode-extensions, prettier

Is there a way to configure Prettier in VSCode to use a tab width of **4** for code files like HTML, CSS, and JS, but a tab width of **2** for **.md** files to prevent yellow error lines?